# Custom Font in Android App

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am working on an android project, the application is already built but just in order to improve the user interface. I am working on restyling the application. 
For that I am also trying to use a custom font, but that is not working. I have gone through the sample codes available on the web but none doesn't solve my problem. 
Here is how I am doing it.

```
    package com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the XML part

```
<com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/offlinesummary"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"          
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/offlinecheckbox"
            android:text="@string/cp_preview_off_desc"
            style="@style/textN_l"> 
           </com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView>
```

Style :

```
 <style name="textN_l" parent="w_h">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>  
 <style name="w_h"> <!-- Width and Height -->
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>        
</style>
```

And the errors I am getting are

```
    06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.license/com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MapControlPanelDialog}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MapControlPanelDialog.onCreate(MapControlPanelDialog.java:72)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     ... 11 more
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     ... 22 more
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView.init(MyTextView.java:27)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView.<init>(MyTextView.java:17)
06-15 08:35:24.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     ... 25 more
```

Thank you

Comment: please post the full logcat, the error you posted has no information

Comment: I am sorry, I have now added the full logcat.

Comment: @FatimaRizwan : if you comment  setTypeface(tf); then working or not?

Comment: Hi Imran, Its not working that way too, I tried.

Comment: @FatimaRizwan what it android:style="@style/textN_l" means   have u have any style with naming textN_l in values folder with style.xml and what u set in it show that also

Comment: @FatimaRizwan : see my answer you need to use Paint or Override draw method to set Custom font in Custom TextView

Comment: Yes I do have style with that name let me add here.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget the namespace?

```
<com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/offlinesummary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"          
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/offlinecheckbox"
        android:text="@string/cp_preview_off_desc"
        android:style="@style/textN_l"> 
</com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView>
```

Comment: What I meant was the `android:` namespace, but looking at your stacktrace, the problem seems to be in the custom font itself. Are you sure you have the "handsean.ttf" in the "fonts" folder within "assets"?

Comment: There is no way you can add style by 'android:style' Its style. 
Yes the font is there, in the assets folder and then in fonts folder.

Comment: I would have posted it in comments. But I did not have enough reputation. Again, the stacktrace clearly mentions the error to be in the constructor of `TypeFace`.

Comment: Another note: the filename is case sensitive. So make sure the filename used in the code is exactly the same as the name of the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the layout width and height. Then, execute the program.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
 private Paint mPaint;  
float middleY=1;  
float mX=30;  
float DY=30; 
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
        mPaint = new Paint();  
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);  
        mPaint.setTextSize(16);  
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
        mPaint.setTypeface(tf); 
          //  setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
    @Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onDraw(canvas);  
        canvas.drawColor(0xEFeffff);  
        Paint p = mPaint;   
        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);          
        canvas.drawText("TESTEST", mX, middleY, p);    

    }
```

Comment: for more help you can view following code for setting custom fonts in TextView https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/customtextview.txt?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: @FatimaRizwan : you try https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/customtextview.txt?attredirects=0&d=1 example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/offlinesummary"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/offlinecheckbox"
    android:text="@string/cp_preview_off_desc"
    android:style="@style/textN_l">
```

**UPDATE**

So other code is looks perfect. Only problem remains is in your ".ttf" file, may be this file is damaged. Download fonts from here developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html and use them.
hope it will work.

Comment: Are you try this?

I have tested it. It is working absolutely perfect.

You need to give the 

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

you are not giving these parameters in your XML.

Comment: oh Sorry I don't see that.

So other code is looks perfect. Only problem remains is in your ".ttf" file, may be this file is damaged.

try to download fonts from hee http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

and used them

Answer (score 0):

u have to use in xml as given below

```
  <com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/offlinesummary"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"          
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/offlinecheckbox"
        android:text="@string/cp_preview_off_desc"
        >
  </com.crittermap.backcountrynavigator.dialog.MyTextView>
```

and in your any activity u have to use this way

```
MyTextView textview=(MyTextView)findViewById(R.id.offlinesummary);
```

Comment: Yes This is how I am doing that.

Comment: @FatimaRizwan i think problem is bcz of style first remove that and check and either also show code of style.xml or styles.xml

Comment: I have added in the question styles code also. Please have a look.